# When VPN client enabled access from 10.8.0.0 segment not possible

Tags: networking, openvpn, route

I have a server which has an OpenVPN client installed and which is connecting to the internet, via the tunnel, just fine. I can also reach the server on the LAN interface (192.168.1.x). However when I try to access the same server from another IP range 10.8.0.x in the LAN it does not work. When I shutdown the VPNClient it again works fine.

Without the VPN client running on the server clients in the 10.8.0.x range can reach the server

```
root@server:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use 
Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 
enp0s31f6
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 
enp0s31f6
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 
enp0s31f6
```

With the VPN client running on the server clients in the 10.8.0.x range can NOT reach the server

```
root@server:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.23.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s31f6
10.23.10.1      10.23.10.5      255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.23.10.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
46.166.188.211  192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enp0s31f6
128.0.0.0       10.23.10.5      128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s31f6
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 enp0s31f6
```

I also tried to add a route for the submit to explicitly tell the network to route 10.8.0.0 traffic over the enp0s31f6 interface.

```
root@server:~# route add -net 10.8.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev enp0s31f6
```

However no luck.

Anyone have an idea why this is?

Comment: You should not use `route` any more. Your command line does not contain the gateway address: `ip route add 10.0.0.0/16 via 192.168.1.1` (after removing your manual entry)

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to manually add any routes for the subnet associated with your VPN `tun` interface. The client should be setting that up for you. Also, adding a route on your Ethernet interface for the `tun` interface will not work due to the way openvpn routes packets.

It seems you should enable `client-to-client` in your server config and make sure you have an `iptables` rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That is not the problem. The problem is that that the VPN configuration may create routing conflicts as it natually doesn not know anything about the local situation.